# UICollectionViewCell Only Updates After Scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've got an issue with my UICollectionView where my cells are always initiated blank/in a default state with no data.

The data only appears in the cells after scrolling them in and out of view.

Code:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"EquipmentCell";
    APInventoryCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (!cell) cell = [[APInventoryCollectionViewCell alloc] init];

    //set cell data...
    cell.label.text = [arrayOfStrings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: where is your arrayOfStrings allocating and getting data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you probably set the `arrayOfStrings` somewhere in the `viewDidLoad` method of your view controller, the problem with that is that the collectionview datasource calls are done before that.

What you should do in your `viewDidLoad` method just call `[collectionview reloadData];` an you will be fine