# UICollectionview loads image after scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, horizontal-scrolling

I am using UICollectioView to show a list of images. The images are stored locally inside the project. The issue is that after scrolling two or three times it shows image.My problem is same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30123864/uicollectionviewcell-only-updates-after-scrolling). But it is not solving the problem.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

 UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


return cell;
}
```

Comment: Be more specific, show some code and [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please see the edit

Comment: "after scrolling two or three times it shows image" What does that mean ?

Comment: It does not show image immediately. It is a horizontal collectionview. After scrolling it populates the image

Comment: if the images are too big the system needs to load them.

Comment: even the labels are not loading

Comment: Post the code for the entire controller, the issue might be elsewhere